# Creating a failure / cumulative incidence / event survival plot with svykm

Tags: r, survey

I have used the twang package to propensity score weight my data and am using the survey package functions.

I am able to create a standard survival curve without issue using the following code:

```
km <- svykm(Surv(rec_time,rec)~procedure, design=design.mnps)
plot(km)
```

I have looked online, and if it wasn't a svykmlist object, the following would work:

```
km <- svykm(Surv(rec_time,rec)~procedure, design=design.mnps, function(x) 1-x)
plot(km)
```

I get the following error:

```
1: In plot.window(...) : "FUN" is not a graphical parameter
```

, etc.

I have also tried FUN="event", which works fine with a traditional survey object but not the svykm object. I have also tried manipulating the survey object, which has been unsuccessful.

Is there anything I haven't tried yet that can work with the svykmlist object?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: You should describe in detail what you want to happen and what plots you want to see. The second assignment to KM appears to be a request to plot instead, the complement of survival, but that's perhaps because we have no idea what part of the "online"-world you might be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

when you post on SO, please use a minimal reproducible example.  the object `design.mnps` isn't useful.  please edit your question and clarify why you aren't simply inverting your function in the formula like this?  thanks

example from ?svykm

```
library(survey)
data(pbc, package="survival")
pbc$randomized <- with(pbc, !is.na(trt) & trt>0)
biasmodel<-glm(randomized~age*edema,data=pbc)
pbc$randprob<-fitted(biasmodel)
dpbc<-svydesign(id=~1, prob=~randprob, strata=~edema, data=subset(pbc,randomized))

s2<-svykm(Surv(time,status>0)~I(bili>6), design=dpbc)
plot(s2)

sz<-svykm(Surv(time,status>0)~I( 1 - I(bili>6) ), design=dpbc)
plot(sz)
```